# Instanciation of ViewModels an Views on top of existing model objects

Tags: c#, wpf, design-patterns, mvvm, instantiation

I am working on a project where I try to implement MVVM to correctly separate the business logic from the views. Eventhough I read a lot of papers on this pattern and looked at sample applications, I still have a few unanswered questions.

My model consists in a set of `Documents` containing a list of `DocumentObjects` of different kinds.

The `DocumentObjects` contain computation logic and have interaction with each other and with the `Document`.

Then I have my Views and ViewModels (one of each for the `Document` and one of each for each kind of `DocumentObjects`)

To implement this in a correct MVVM pattern, I would make my `DocumentView` to display the `DocumentObjects` list (with an `ItemsControl` for example). WPF would then choose the right view to use via a DataTemplate entry.

The problem with this method is that I want to keep in my `Document`, a list of the actual `DocumentObjects` and not their viewmodels. Then if I use a DataTemplate to describe wich view to use for the objects, I can't specify the viewmodel I wish to use...

**My question is** : How can I build the "VVM" part on top already existing model objects, without them knowing ?
Or more realistically, how would you change this design pattern to comply with MVVM guidelines ?

(What I want is a kind of "model-first" instantiation.)

**One of the sample apps, that raises my question :** In [Reed Copsey's blog post on MVVM](http://reedcopsey.com/2010/01/07/better-user-and-developer-experiences-from-windows-forms-to-wpf-with-mvvm-conclusion/) :

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type model:FeedItem}">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Title}" />
</DataTemplate>
```

The `FeedItem` model is directly use by the view using a `DataTemplate`. How could it be done if the `FeedItem` had to have a `ViewModel` ?

(I am aware that my design might not be the best and am open to suggestions !).

Answer (score 1):

I don't quite follow your question exactly, but it sounds like you want to augment a model with some additional properties that you're going to expose to your view, which is what a view model is for.

For example you may have a `Document` model which has a collection of `Item`:

```
public class Document
{
    public List<Item> Items { get; set; }
}
```

You wish to render each item in a view with some additional properties that aren't on the `Item` type. You don't want to pollute your `Item` model with these additional properties which are a concern of the view, so you create an `ItemViewModel`. You would typically then create a `DocumentViewModel` to hold this collection:

```
public class DocumentViewModel
{
    public List<ItemViewModel> ItemViewModels { get; set; }
}
```

Your view would then bind to an instance of your `DocumentViewModel`. There would obviously need to be some plumbing code which transfers the data to and from your `Document` and `DocumentViewModel` types. You can use libraries such as [AutoMapper](http://automapper.codeplex.com/) to aid this.

You may of course decide that your `Document` type already contains all of the required properties, and you wish to expose it directly to your view. This is a balance between the DRY and LoD principles, so you'll have to consider that.

The most important thing though is that [if you're doing MVVM, then you need to use an MVVM framework](http://www.lhotka.net/weblog/UsingTheMVVMPatternRequiresAFramework.aspx). This would also help greatly with view composition. For example with [Caliburn.Micro](http://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/), the conventions assume that any collection you're binding to is a collection of view models, and it will automatically locate the corresponding view and bind the two together.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Although it's not exactly what I wanted (I admit that my question wasnt the clearest), I followed your advice and started using Caliburn.Micro to take care of a part of the heavy MVVM job. I'll see if it suits my need in a little time !